# SubSonic Generates Namespace, but my website doesn't recognize it.

Tags: mysql, templates, subsonic, subsonic3, namespaces

I've got a pretty basic setup in Visual Studio 2008 - Website project referencing my class library project. SubSonic 3 is referenced from both projects, but the template has been modified for my MySQL db. It connects and generates the most of code (except for stored procedures, for some reason), and the namespace is there, and my intellisense picks it up while coding in the website project, I still get build errors saying that the namespace doesn't exist.

It's driving me crazy, and it know (hope) it's probably simple, but I've not had enough sleep to rationalize the problem.  Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

-Zam

P.S. I've used SubSonic earlier versions, but never with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Does the project reference the subsonic dll and the [mysql .net connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html)?